# Solving invalid_grant errors

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

If you're trying to get an access token and facing an invalid_grant error.

You have controled that the all parameters are ok.

It may due to the clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your server's clock is in sync with NTP.

1. Open a cmd as Administrator
2. run this command :
   w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:0.pool.ntp.org,1.pool.ntp.org,2.pool.ntp.org,3.pool.ntp.org
3. net stop w32time
4. net start w32time
5. Try again to get an access_token

Hope it help you!

I've spent some hours to find out the cause of the problem...

Comment: also remind that "iat" and "exp" are **seconds** since 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970, not **millis**... (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)